# GitHub (Mac application) - commits not visible

Tags: macos, github, commit

I have just recently installed the github mac application and attempted to push some existing commits to a branch using the Synchronise button. I am authenticated with SSH keys, the application did not complain and it seemed to work. However, when inspecting the remote repository on github.com I cannot seem to find my commits anywhere, not in the history of the branch or individual files. It's as if I had committed nothing.

However, inside the GitHub app i can click on the "view on github" button and it will inspect the commits and show the diffs etc. correctly as if i had navigated to them on the website.

Does anybody know why this may be happening? Apologies in advance if this is a trivial problem!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right, but did you first commit and then use the sync button?

Comment: Sorry, the commits existed prior to installing the application - i had made them from the command line git utility.

Comment: Not quite, i still cannot find them on github.com. My git log shows the commits correctly and git pull origin branch suggests I am already up to date - they are just no where to be found. Very strange!

Comment: if you work on the console now, did you also push or just commit?

Comment: I had not pushed via console, only committed. I used the sync button inside the github application to try and do the push.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can "split it up", doing one part on the console and the other part in the app. Maybe you can now push your commits via the console and use the app afterwards.